# Creating new layer within DXF file

Tags: python, ogr, layers, dxf

Using OGR in Python, I'd like to create some geometries within a DXF file, but not in the "0" layer, but in new ones.

I tried with:

```
import ogr, os, osr, sys
ds = ogr.GetDriverByName('DXF').CreateDataSource('output.dxf' )
myLayer = ds.CreateLayer('entities')
newFeature = ogr.Feature(feature_def = myLayer.GetLayerDefn())
newFeature.SetGeometryDirectly(ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt( 'LINESTRING(0 0, 100 100)'))
myLayer.CreateFeature( newFeature )
newFeature.Destroy()
ds.Destroy()
ds = None
```

But I don't have any idea about how to continue and create new layers.

I tried also with

```
layers = ds.ExecuteSQL("INSERT INTO entities (Layer) VALUES ('Layer1')")
```

but it does not work.

Do you have any suggestion as to why not?

Answer (score 1):

'layer' is an attribute field. Add:

```
newFeature.SetField( myLayer.GetLayerDefn().GetFieldIndex("layer"), 'newlayer')
```

And the feature will appear on layer *newlayer*.